# Custom domain URL in Apigee, leading me to blank 'domains' page

Tags: google-cloud-functions, apigee

I am currently following the [documentation](https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/publish/portal/custom-domain#configuring-tls) of Apigee to set up a custom domain. I am using a google cloud function as my API. I have a URL registered with google domains, and have configured TLS and created a keystore. I am now attempting to [add a custom domain.](https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/publish/portal/custom-domain#step_3_add_a_custom_domain_name_to_your_portal)

The first three instructions are:

```
1. Select Publish > Portals and select your portal..
2. Select Settings in the drop-down menu in the top navigation bar or on the landing page.
3. Click the Domains tab.
```

However when I click on the Domains tab, I get a blank screen.

[image]

Am I doing something wrong? I have reached out to support but have not received feedback.